# will a force with same frequency as natural frequency make system resonance (in multi-dof)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vibrations

assume we have a multi-dof system and a force is applied with same frequency as one of the natural frequencies. will this system be resonant in any circumstances?
(system is undamped).

Answer (score 0):

If the whole system is linear, you could decompose the system motion as 
$$ \vec{x} = {\bf{\Phi}} \vec{q}$$
Where $\vec{q}$ are the modal coordinates. If you translate your equations of motions from generalised coordinates to modal coordinates you will obtain 
$$ \ddot{\vec{q}} + {\bf{\Gamma}} \vec{q} =  {\bf{\Phi}}^T \vec{F}$$

Where {\bf{\Gamma}} is a diagonal matrix with the square of the natural frequency of every mode along its diagonal. ${\bf{\Phi}}$ represents the normal modes directions, and are orthogonal between them. You can calculate ${\bf{\Gamma}}$ and ${\bf{\Phi}}$ as the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of ${\bf{M}}^{-1}{\bf{K}}$, being ${\bf{M}}$ the generalised mass matrix and ${\bf{K}}$ the generalised stiffness.

Note now that the forces contributes over your system by the product ${\bf{\Phi}} \vec{F}$, as consequence, to make the mode $i$ to enter in resonance not only $\vec{F}$ has to be in exciting the right frequency but $\vec{\phi}_i^T \vec{F}$ has to be compatible, i.e. they can not be orthogonal.